# Linq2Db using a Column in an Update Statement

Tags: c#, sql-update, linq2db

I want to recreate the following SQL Update Command in LINQ to DB (Linq2DB).

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET TextColumn = CONCAT(TextColumn, char(13), char(10), 'New Text')
WHERE TextColum IS NOT NULL
```

I don't know how to implement this with Linq2Db because I don't know how to get access to the Column to use it as a Value.

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
  db.MyTable
    .Where(p => p.TextColumn != null)
    .Set(p => p.TextColumn, ???)    
    .Update();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special here, just repeat what to do with column.

```cs
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
    db.MyTable
        .Where(p => p.TextColumn != null)
        .Set(p => p.TextColumn, p => p.TextColumn + "New Text")    
        .Update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry my Visual Studio apparently got confused yesterday. Today everything works, as you showed. Thanks for the great work with Linq2Db, really love it!